# If condition in ADF Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a data flow as follows:

[image]

[image]

What I'm trying to do is:

1. if environment = prod, store data to Sink
2. if environment != prod, do a filter and store data to Sink.

using Conditional Split. On running this data flow, I don't see any data being added to the Sink. What am I missing?

Note: $environment is a parameter set for Data Flow:

[image]

Comment: which is your column name,`environment ` or `$environment `?

Comment: $environment is a parameter I set for mapping data flow (shown above)

Comment: When you test it using Data Preview inside the Data Flow designer window, do you see the Split condition working properly there?

Comment: Any errors output? This dataflow works fine on my side.

Comment: can you please check removing single quotes to prod in 'environment' parameter value